# Is it possible to "Inspect" a UWP windows app

Tags: html, visual-studio, windows-store-app

I have a UWP App i am working on made with Angular, HTML & css, but developing it is tricky.

With usual web dev you can press F12 in your browser (or ctrl-shift-j) to open the console window, and access many nifty features such as "inspect" and the ability to browse the html.

With a my UWP App even though it is written most entirely like a webpage i do not know if it possible to enable this level of debugging functionality, and it is making it way harder to developer.

Is this possible? or am i wishing for a non-existant feature?

Thanks!

Comment: [Deploying and debugging UWP apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps)

Answer (score 0):

While the UWP app is running in Visual Studio with the debugger attached you have access to the visual tree in the Live Visual Tree panel.  Apart from that you're out of luck.